# Detect role mention discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I have a command which locks out the @everyone role from sending messages to a channel. I would like to make so that the user could run the command and mention a specific role along with it and then the members of that role will be blocked from sending messages.
Here is my code so far which only locks the everyone role:

```
if (!message.guild.me.hasPermission(`MANAGE_CHANNELS`)) return message.reply('I lack the required permissions to run this command. (Required Permissions: ``MANAGE_CHANNELS``)');          
        if(message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")){
            const channel = message.channel
            const Discord = require("discord.js")
            let replyMessage = message.reply("Are you sure you want to continue this command, it will remove send permissions from the everyone role. Type ``yes`` to continue.")
            let filter = msg => msg.author.id == message.author.id && msg.content.toLowerCase() == 'yes';
            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 1, time: 20000}).then(collected => {
            
                message.reply('Confirmed!');

                message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.everyone, {
                SEND_MESSAGES: false
                })
                .then(channel => channel.send("Channel Locked"))
                .catch(console.error);
            });
```

I couldn't find much on checking role mentioning but I have this and was wondering if you could just change the `message.mentions.**members**.first()` and replace it with `message.mentions.**roles**.first()`:

```
let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

and was wondering if anyone could help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can replace

```js
message.mentions.users.first()
```

with

```js
message.mentions.roles.first()
```

This would look like this:

```js
let role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === args.join(" ");
```